# How to break JSON data in multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a html code and it it working fine for small json file and showing  data in html table properly. But my problem is now that i have a big json file around 15000 html table row. So my page is not responding. How can i break 100 result per page till last result. I am sharing my html code.Please add some code in my html file and paste in answer section

```
<html>
<header><title>Welcome</title></header>
<body>
<!--javascript make append table data-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#userdata tbody").empty();
$(function() {
var user = document.getElementById("userId").value;
    var category = location.search.split('id=')[1]
   $.getJSON('abc.php',{"userId":user,"categoryId":category}, function(data) {
 $.each(data.videos , function(i, v) {
     var link = "youtube.php?id=youtu.be/"+ v.video;
         var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + v.videoName + "</td>" + "<td>" + v.date + "</td>" +"<td>"+ v.time + "</td>" + "<td>" + v.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+"WATCH/DOWNLOAD"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>";
          $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });
   });

   $.getJSON('crp.php',{"userId":user,"categoryId":category}, function(data) {
 $.each(data.other , function(i, f) {

        var link =f.pdf;

          tblRows2 = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.dateText + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.textMessage + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+"Click here to Download"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>";
          $(tblRows2).appendTo("#userdata2 tbody");
});
     });
   });
</script>
<!--javascript  append table data ended -->
<!-- user form -->
<form>
    <input id='userId' type="hidden" value="500" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>
</form>
<!-- user form -->
<!--table-->
<h1>VIDEO LIST</h1>

<!--<style>
.wrapper {
    table tr td:nth-child(5) {
        background: white;
    }
}

.profile {
table, th, tr {
  border: 5px solid green;
  background:5px black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
}
}

</style>-->

<!--<style>
.button {

  border: 5px solid green;
  background:5px black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
}
</style>-->
   <table class="button" id= "userdata" width="100%" border="20">
  <thead>
            <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME</th>
            <th>DURATION</th>
            <th>LINK</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
   </table>
<!--table data end-->
<!--table-->
</body>
<body>
<style>
table tr td:nth-last-of-type(1) {
    background: white;
}
table, th, tr {
  border: 5px solid green;
  background:5px black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<h1>PDF LIST</h1>
<div class="wrapper2">
<div class="profile2">
   <table id= "userdata2" width="100%" border="20">
       <thead>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>LINK</th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can set limit in your PHP file of 100

Comment: please explain more sir

Comment: Use pagination on the data so that you can send a fixed no. of data at once.

Comment: use query for e.g. `SELECT * FROM datatable
LIMIT 100; ` to fetch required data at time in your php file

Answer (score 0):

**you have multiple options**

1-use pagination like 1,2,3,4,etc

->this can be done using js and php or php with sql setting limit on your query and shift it when you choose another page

2-lazy loading on scroll -> this can be done using js

example using php with my sql
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm